# How to transform DIV-Container with CSS3

Tags: html, css

I try to transform my div container like the following picture.

[image: css perspec]

Left is a normal div container painted black. On the right is the container i want to have.

Do you know how to solve this in css3 ? i read something about the "Polygon" attribute in css3, but i also heard that this attribut was removed.

edit: when content is in the box it would be screchted - the box is like "falling in the back".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an [article](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/) at css-tricks.com regarding this a while back. This may work:

```
#trapezoid {
    border-bottom: 100px solid red;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    height: 0;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But i think it would not work. i'll tryit - but its solved with borders. I need to put Content in it and to "let it fall" - the fall i solve with "rotateX 70deg" - but with this the container just "fall" - but the container borders dont "fall" ... its just like a box that is smaller than before - just the content is like falling down.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked fine with adding the roateX attribut. (: Problem solved!

Comment: No problem. I haven't figured out how it works yet, but I will, in time.

Answer (score 1):

```
    #trapezoid { 
 border-bottom: 100px solid black;
 border-left: 50px solid transparent; 
 border-right: 50px solid transparent; 
 height: 0; width: 100px; }
```

Check [here](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/) for more shapes and tricks